# GridLayout does not expand elements evenly

Tags: android, grid-layout

i am trying to use GridView to divide the screen into six equal pieces. The problem is that it displays properly in the emulator but when i view it from the phone then the space is distributed unevenly. What could cause this behavior?

I have tested this with API 21 & API 22 phones.

Emulator vs Phone:

[image: emulator] [image: phone]

This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.myapp.myapp.myapp.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:columnCount="2"
            android:rowCount="3"
            android:layout_centerInParent="false">

            <Button
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1.0"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1.0"
                android:text="c0 | r0" />

            <Button
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1.0"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1.0"
                android:text="c1 | r0" />

            <Button
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1.0"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1.0"
                android:text="c0 | r1" />

            <Button
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1.0"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1.0"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:text="c1 | r1" />

            <Button
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1.0"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1.0"
                android:text="c0 | r2" />

            <Button
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1.0"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1.0"
                android:text="c1 | r2" />
        </GridLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the layout weight works only with `LinearLayout` but you are using `RelativeLayout`. Try to switch it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, tried with LinearLayout - issue still persists.

Comment: Can you try commenting out android:layout_alignParentBottom, android:layout_alignParentRight and android:layout_alignParentEnd in the GridLayout?

Comment: Still the same result.