# GridLayout does not display properly, doesn't match preview

Tags: android-layout, preview

This question has been asked but not answered so I will add another instance of it. Original is here, it is exactly my problem. Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.slidamusic.gridlayoutdemo.GridDemo">

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
   >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"

        android:layout_row="0"

        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button1"

        android:layout_row="0"

        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_column="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button2"

        android:layout_row="1"

        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button3"

        android:layout_row="1"

        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_column="1" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button4"

        android:layout_row="2"

        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button5"

        android:layout_row="2"

        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_column="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button6"

        android:layout_row="3"

        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button7"

        android:layout_row="3"

        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_column="1" />



</GridLayout>
```

It is as very simple layout of 8 buttons that in the preview are all perfectly aligned and identically sized in 2 cols and 4 rows. When I run the program on my tablet, things are much more disorderly, more or less like this:

[GridLayout does not expand elements evenly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36977058/gridlayout-does-not-expand-elements-evenly)

I have hypothesized that the problem may be with android:layout_gravity="fill" as when I remove this line the buttons are of normal size and they line up just fine, but they do not fill up the screen as I would like, and as it is shown in the preview.

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered the problem. It is about lack of compatibility with older APIs.

layout_rowWeight and layout_columnWeight are only usable with API 21 and higher. My device uses API 17. There may be a solution to this problem, but probably the best idea is to use some other sort of formatting to achieve the same visual result, such as hardcoding the size of the buttons.

I am taking an online course and following the construction of the programs exactly, thus I was specifically interested in why this wasn't working. I had the preview on Android Studio set to API 23. Setting it to the appropriate API for my testing device would have shown me accurately how the program was going to look. If someone sees this and has an idea on how to use these attributes in lower APIs, I'd be interested in learning how to do it.

Android Studio itself has a warning about the use of these attributes and I finally noticed it. Could have saved a tremendous amount of time!